# Chromium Needs an Update On Raspbarian pi3. Now Asking For An Update!

Tags: raspbian, pi-3, chromium

itv.com streaming won't play because Chromium needs an update from version 72.
Anybody know of? Or how to contact the developers?
Annoying because it was working fine before.

Comment: Thanks for your help everyone. I didn't realize there was another version of Raspbian (Buster). I have updated and now working fine.Thanks Again.

Answer (score 3):

You don't tell us what Raspbian version do you use, but with Raspbian **buster** I will get:

```
rpi ~$ apt show chromium-browser
Package: chromium-browser
Version: 74.0.3729.157-rpt5
Priority: optional
Section: web
Maintainer: Ubuntu Developers <ubuntu-devel-discuss@lists.ubuntu.com>
Installed-Size: 289 MB
Provides: chromium, chromium-browser-inspector, www-browser
--- snip ---
```

As you can see you will have Chromium version **74.0**.3729.157-rpt5 that is updated from version 72.0. So I suggest to use an up to date operating system.

Answer (score 2):

You have Chromium 72? That means you are not running running Raspbian Buster, and most likely running Stretch.
Older operating systems are unsupported, so it is a good idea to [download](https://www.raspberrypi.org/downloads/) and install a Buster image.

But if for some reason upgrading to Buster is not an option, you can update your current operating system.

Run this in the terminal to update your system:

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt full-upgrade -y
sudo apt autoremove -y
```

First command makes the package manager become "aware" of possible updates.
Second command installs those updates and removes the old versions.
Third command removes any unused/unnecessary packages.

(Yes I made sure chromium 74 is available for Stretch)

Comment: You are not right. [Raspbian Buster (Lite) 2019-07-10](https://downloads.raspberrypi.org/raspbian_lite/images/raspbian_lite-2019-07-12/) comes with chromium-browser **74.0**.3729.157-rpt4. I have just looked at it on a fresh flashed image. The commands you have given may upgrade the operating system but with the chromium-browser it will not update a major version because there isn't a version 72.0 that can be updated. V74 is just available.

Comment: @Ingo, excellent observation. According to the [changelog](https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=243387), Raspbian Buster shipped with Chromium 74, even while in beta. I have fixed my answer.